# Black screen on a Dell inspiron 1501 with a Radeon Xpress 200M

Tags: 11.04, radeon, nomodeset

When attempting to run the ubuntu 11.04 live CD on my wife's laptop, I consistently get a black screen with multicolored vertical bars - no video.

This happens only when using kernel mode setting. When i boot with modesetting off, it boots without problems. However, I'm not really interested in using natty in fallback mode, and would like to try out the 3d accelerated version. I believe that it should be supported on my hardware (Radeon RS482 - Radeon Xpress 200M).

Is this just a bug for which there is currently no fix, or is there some workaround for it?

**Update:** This also happens with the latest 11.10 beta1.

Comment: Well that happens because it doesn't support it, the AMD driver doesn't support it and if the other choice which is the RadeonHD open source driver for 3D accel. doesn't work you're out of luck.

Comment: umm..do you know this or are you just making assumptions? As mentioned in my question, my video card [should be supported](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/RadeonXpress)

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this today for my laptop containing the same Radeon Xpress 200M video chipset.

The trick is to force the radeon kernel driver to load early in the boot process.

Add 'radeon' to the file `/etc/initramfs-tools/modules`

Run `update-initramfs -u`  afterwards to update the initrd image for your kernel.